# JSDoc: How to define a destructured function parameter with a default value of no function?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Given function `f({ val1, func1 })` where `val1` is an integer, and `func1` is a function, how can I create a JSDoc definition that indicates func1 is an *optional* function, as well as assign the function a default value in the function declaration?  (Currently assigning 'false' as the default value, but VSCode then assumes the `func1` parameter is boolean. Do I need to use `void` to indicate no function is passed?)

For example:

```
function f({ val1 = 0, func1 = false })
/**
 * @description This is a function that does something.
 @ @param {Object} params - This is the function's parameters
 * @param {number} [params.val1=0] - This is a number that does something
 * @param {function} [params.func1=false] = This is a function that does something
 * @returns {number}
*/
{
    if (va1 != 0)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    
    if (func1)
    {
        val1 += func1(val1);
    }
    return val1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few things wrong here. First your jsdoc comment should go on the line(s) above your function declaration. As soon as you do that, your IDE will show you that you've got a few errors--the first being that your code is referencing `va1` whereas the param is `val1`, the second leading to your question.

But the big thing is you're mixing javascript assumptions into your types. The IDE will point out that `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Function'`, you can easily fix this by typing it as `function|boolean` but as soon as you do that then your if block will assume that your `func` value is either a function or true. So that's not quite it either.

You could go one step further and type it as specifically `function|false` and then the IDE knows that if it's not false, then it must be a function and be fine. However, mixing types like that for this basic case is weird. What you probably actually want to do is to type your function as `function|null` and then instead of defaulting it to false, you can then default it to `null` and it will work like you're expecting.

Lastly what I would instead suggest is to specifically type your function as `@param { (arg0: number) => number} [params.func1=() => 0]` and have `() => 0` be your default value. Then the IDE will tell you when you try to pass a value into it that's not an integer, and knows that you're allowed to do math with that function.